# Difference between int(c) and c-'0'. C++

Tags: c++, char, ascii

Consider the following fragment of code:

```
char c = 'a';
std::cout << int(c) << " " << c - '0' << std::endl;
```

Here my output is `97 49`.

Can anyone hint me what the difference between them?
For example if I am trying to find the number of duplicate characters in the string:

```
int duplicates[256];
//.. run over string
1. duplicates[c]++;
2. duplicates[c-'0']++;
```

So which one I should choose and whats the difference between them?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about negative character values too

Comment: 97 is the numeric value of the character `'a'`. 48 is the numeric value of the character `'0'`. 49 is the difference between the two. Don't use `c - '0'`, because your string might contain a character that's less than `'0'`. See http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @John "*Don't use `c - '0'`*" - it is perfectly OK to use, as long as you ensure `c` is numeric first, such as with [`std::isdigit()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should answer to your question:

```
char c = 'a';
std::cout << int(c)  << " "<< int('0') << " " << c - '0' << std::endl;
```

if you run it the output is `97 48 49`, because `97 -> 'a'` `48 -> '0'` and so `49 -> '0'`, which can be also written as `97 - 48 -> '0'`.

Chars under the hood are integers, and so you can go through them with arithmetic operator. (check [this](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).

This means that if you have a `string` or a `char *` and you want to count all the occurrence of each char, you should use

```
int duplicates[256];
duplicates[c]++;
```

because for example if your string is `"\1"` for some reason, and you do `duplicates[c-'0']++;` the array index will be a negative number, and so undefined behavior (this assuming that you don't do any checks before the increments, for example checking if is inside a specific bound)

Answer (score 0):

The number zero and the character symbol "0" are two completely different things. The only thing they have in common as that the symbol "0" is sometimes used as a way to represent the number zero.

```
std::cout << int(c) << " " << c - '0' << std::endl;
```

This subtracts whatever code your platform uses to represent the character "0". It is almost certainly not the number zero.